# VC++ 2010 include/lib path

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there a place to set header and library path for ALL projects in VC2010 express?
When i set them they seem to only apply to a single project (eg i have to set them everytime i start a new project).

Comment: i used to be able to in VC2005/8 :(

Comment: It's probably a bad idea/bad practice, unless you're just a one-person team.

Comment: what about libraries like directx etc? things i use more often then not

Comment: I generally tend to put them all in the projects, but I see your point.  IF the entire team sets the configuration the same then that would work fine.

Comment: i found a good answer here
http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the env vars: INCLUDE and LIBPATH for this.

Not sure how to do it from the GUI - but from the control panel it is straightforward.  I don't know if Visual Studio appends to that or just sets/overwrites it though.

Comment: can you explain more? I set INCLUDE to `C:\dev\external\include;` in user environment variable and reopen one instance of visual studio and had no luck.

Comment: Like this http://i41.tinypic.com/1zmkns0.jpg NOTE: There were no include/libpath variables before.

Answer (score 1):

Use property sheet files. *.vsprops Change default one for the platform you need. They are under Property Manager Tab, near Solution Explorer.

See this MSDN help for mor information: "[VC++ Directories Property Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.TOOLSOPTIONSPAGES.PROJECTS.VCDIRECTORIES%29&rd=true)"