# Custom macros for configuring a build in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate.  I tried to search for an answer to my question, but the word 'macro' just has too many different applications to filter the search results very effectively.

Anyway, I recently noticed in another Visual C++ (VS2010) project that custom macros were used to set up VC++ directories (include, lib) or link libraries.  Something like this: "libjpeg-$(JPEG_LIB_VERSION)-static.lib", etc.

**How does one go about doing that?**  I can't remember in what project I saw that technique, so I haven't been able to find it again to investigate, but this would be very useful when building against local builds or particular versions of widely-distributed software (say, Boost, for instance).

There's this ([Visual C++ Express and setting env variables solution wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335030/visual-c-express-2010-and-setting-env-variables-solution-wide)), which I suppose kinda-sorta answers the question, but not really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro being used may be an environment variable, or it may indeed be a custom macro.

If it is an environment variable, you could follow the documentation as mentioned in this MSDN document [How to: Use Environment Variables in a Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx)

However, if it is not an environment variable and you want to create your own, there is another MSDN document for that [How to: Add New Property Sheets to C++ Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k4a0033%28VS.80%29.aspx)

For additional references on creating a custom macro, please see [How to add environmental variable to VS solution (.sln )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634466/how-to-add-environmental-variable-to-vs-solution-sln)

For additional references on using an environment, please see [Macros/Environment variable in .sln and .vcproj files for Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840472/macros-environment-variable-in-sln-and-vcproj-files-for-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for all the references.  I figure you're probably right to point out that environment variables can be used in a build.